# ssldump: PCAP: syntax error

Tags: networking, freebsd, ssl

I'm using:

```
# uname -ro
FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE-p3
```

And the latest `ssldump`:

```
# pkg_info | grep ssldump
ssldump-0.9b3_4     SSLv3/TLS network protocol analyzer
```

When I try starting it with decryption - I got the following error:

```
# ssldump -Xnd -i em0 port 8443 -k name.pem -p password
PCAP: syntax error
```

I've installed `libpcap`:

```
# pkg_info | grep libpcap
dnstop-20121017     Captures and analyzes DNS traffic (or analyzes libpcap dump
libpcap-1.4.0       Ubiquitous network traffic capture library
```

Found one reference about possible problems with some network interfaces:

> Support  is  provided  for  only  for  Ethernet and loopback interfaces

So I tried to eun `ssldump` with `lo0`:

```
# ssldump -Xnd -i lo0 port 8443 -k name.pem -p password
PCAP: syntax error
```

So - how I can run`ssldump` with packets decryption? Where is my mistake?

Comment: http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/10000/200/sol10209.html

Answer (score 1):

The [example(s)](https://blogs.oracle.com/jyrivirkki/entry/using_ssldump) I found shos the command like this:

```
$ sudo ssldump -i bge0 -d -k /tmp/myserverkey port 8088
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Then I connect to my server from a browser:

New TCP connection #1: laptop(39699) <-> myserver(8088)
1 1  0.0853 (0.0853)  C>S SSLv2 compatible client hello
  Version 3.1
  cipher suites
  Unknown value 0x39
  Unknown value 0x38
  Unknown value 0x35
  Unknown value 0x33
  Unknown value 0x32
  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  Unknown value 0x2f
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  Unknown value 0xfeff
  TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  Unknown value 0xfefe
  TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA
  TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
  TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5
1 2  0.0856 (0.0002)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerHello
        Version 3.1
        session_id[32]=
          08 22 c2 25 34 4e 85 61 dd 24 ba 9a 59 a2 dc b0
          77 a0 3f b7 ac c9 d3 ce 76 4a b5 42 cc 44 30 fb
        cipherSuite         TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        compressionMethod                   NULL
      Certificate
      ServerHelloDone
1 3  6.1870 (6.1013)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientKeyExchange
1 4  6.1870 (0.0000)  C>S  ChangeCipherSpec
1 5  6.1870 (0.0000)  C>S  Handshake
      Finished
1 6  6.1931 (0.0061)  S>C  ChangeCipherSpec
1 7  6.1931 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
      Finished
1 8  6.2852 (0.0921)  C>S  application_data
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: myserver:8088
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X Mach-O; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041217
    Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,\*/\*;q=0.5
    Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,\*;q=0.7
    Keep-Alive: 300
    Connection: keep-alive

    ---------------------------------------------------------------
1 9  6.2859 (0.0007)  S>C  application_data
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
    Server: Sun-Java-System-Web-Server/7.0
    Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2006 08:12:15 GMT
    Content-length: 142
    Content-type: text/html
```

#### Getting your .pem keyfile

*excerpt from [Jyri Virkki's Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/jyrivirkki/entry/using_ssldump)*

> If given access to the server private key, `ssldump` can decrypt the traffic to and from that server on the fly. That's where it gets really useful. We'll need to do a bit of prep work to set this up.
>
> First, extract the private key from the server instance into a PKCS#12 format file using `pk12util`.
>
> You'll need to know the nickname of the server keypair/cert (see your `server.xml`) for the `-n` parameter.
>
> I changed to the directory where the NSS `*.db` files live so I type `"-d ."`. Alternatively you could run the command from elsewhere by giving the right path.
>   Finally, I'm running JES Web Server 7.0 so there is no prefix to the NSS files, but if you are on 6.1 you'll need to give a `-P` parameter with the right prefix for that instance.
>
> ```
>    $ pk12util -o myserver.pk12 -n Server-Cert -d . -v
>     Enter Password or Pin for "NSS Certificate DB":
>     Enter password for PKCS12 file:
>     Re-enter password:
>     pk12util: PKCS12 EXPORT SUCCESSFUL
> ```
>
> Perhaps needless to say, but if this was a production server I'd have to be very careful where I store this private key file. Keep that in mind.
>
> Next I'll just convert this to a format suitable for `ssldump` using `openssl`:
>
> ```
>    $ openssl pkcs12 -in myserver.pk12 -out myserverkey
>     Enter Import Password:
>     MAC verified OK
>     Enter PEM pass phrase:
>     Enter PEM pass phrase:
>     Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
> ```

#### References

- [Using ssldump](https://blogs.oracle.com/jyrivirkki/entry/using_ssldump)
- [How to Decrypt a Network Trace by using the ssldump Utility](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116978)
- [Troubleshooting TLS Problems With ssldump](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/troubleshooting-tls-problems-with-ssldump#.Ut_f4zco7FQ)

Answer (score 1):

Any "additional" option must be used before "specified" (or vice versa in this definitions :-)).

Wrong way:

```
# ssldump -i em0 port 8443 -a
PCAP: syntax error
```

Right way:

```
# ssldump -a -i em0 port 8443
```

`PCAP: syntax error` Here means error in `ssldump` start options - not anywhere in system configuration.